# Normalizing Redux State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, normalize

I am trying to make a simple form builder.

Assume I have a canvas that will contain some of the rows and every row will have some of the columns and inside a column, they will have the input itself.

My current state shape:

```
const state = {
  row: [{
    id: 1,
    created: '',
    col: [{ type: 'text' }, { type: 'tel' }],
  }, {
    id: 2,
    created: '',
    col: [{ type: 'number' }, { type: 'button' }],
  }],
};
```

Using the above shape, it's really hard for me to manipulate the data. i have already read the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) but I still don't get it. Please help me find the best shape of this state by normalizing it. Any help would be really appreciated.

Here is a quick demo, how that data would be used for my form [Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMM1KOFbwLo)

Comment: What is the difficulty in manipulating data? It looks pretty straight-forward. If you want an easy way, try some of the immutability helpers: https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper. In general, you will have to slice rows, copy the nth object, slice columns, and push an item to the columns array.

Comment: I actually already use that structure for a while, I also use immutability helper to update my data. But at some point, i feel like this structure is quite intimidating and could be simplified. That's why I am looking for another solution

Comment: You could just flatten it out based on fields with each field having a row and column index. But that might make your rendering a bit complex!

Comment: Could you give me an example of flattening that data? thanks

Comment: Have you tried using [Normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr), it is recommended for normalizing your data.

Comment: @VipulPanth Oh, I thought normalizr is only used for normalizing API, is that possible to use that for my state?

Comment: @Hastalab, I don't believe it should be restricted to API data, I mean an object is an object whether you are predefining it or you are using API to load your initial state.

Comment: try using [normalized-reducer](https://github.com/brietsparks/normalized-reducer)

Answer (score 1):

The redux state can be flattened. Have a fields state with each field having a rowIndex and colIndex.

```
const state = {
  fields: [{
    id: 1,
    created: '',
    type: 'text',
    rowIndex: 0,
    colIndex: 0
  }, {
    id: 2,
    created: '',
    type: 'tel',
    rowIndex: 0,
    colIndex: 1
  }, {
    id: 3,
    created: '',
    type: 'number',
    rowIndex: 1,
    colIndex: 0 
  }, {
    id: 4,
    created: '',
    type: 'button',
    rowIndex: 1,
    colIndex: 1 
  }]
}
```